# Get 12 V stable output from solar connected 12 V battery

Tags: voltage, solar-cell, 12v

I have a 12 V monitor on my sailboat that only accepts a 5% voltage difference, so it needs between 11.4 V and 12.6 V input. Max draw is 1.5 amp according to spec. Here is a link to the user manual: https://www.elecrow.com/download/product/DISSF101P/10.1_Inch_Touc_screen_Monitor_User_Manual.pdf

My 12 V system is connected to a solar panel and MPPT charger and so the voltage is higher when the sun is shining and the batteries charging.

I tried using a voltage regulator, but it needs at least 1.5 V difference between the input and output voltage, usually it is less than that (just over 12.6 V).

How can I make sure the voltage is close enough to 12 V for the monitor to operate correctly, independent of the output of the solar panel/MPPT charger?

Comment: Can you give a model name for the monitor, or at least an information about the monitor's consumption?

Comment: Google "low dropout 12V regulator" there are a few circuits in the results which will work with about 0.2V dropout. As your battery should not be discharged below about 12V that should work fine.

Comment: It is very likely the monitor will work with much less than 12V and the tolerance spec is woo-woo. You coud check. Going up in voltage is riskier. How much current does the monitor use?

Comment: i would just add in a buck+boost DC-DC smps, and set it to 12v. That way you get the same 12v out from 11v or 13v in. should cost under $3 per amp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How can I make sure the voltage is close enough to 12 volt for the
> monitor to operate correctly, independent of the output of the solar
> panel/MTTP charger?*

Within certain power limits for the load and minimal power produced by the SPs, you could employ what is known as a buck-boost regulator to achieve what you want.

- [TI link to their converter chips](https://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/buck-boost-inverting/buck-boost-inverting-split-rail-converters-integrated-switch/products.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app-bmc-bcs-58700006661242879_Buck_Boost_Converter_Circuit-cpc-pt-google-eu&utm_content=Buck_Boost_Converter_Circuit&ds_k=buck+boost+converter+circuit&DCM=yes&gclid=CjwKCAjw2rmWBhB4EiwAiJ0mtexUJWiZKD6fTkSoT7PqQpZbwb_D3iyJIwTn5kxQAQi_USaCMJPMihoCW_gQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)
- [Analoge devices link to their converters](https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/buck-boost-regulators.html)

Possibly one that might be of interest: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am looking where I can source a a buck-boost regulator here in South Africa where I currently reside.

Comment: @dhuyvetter good luck and maybe first you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give help for free and also how to close down this Q and A session. I think Mouser and Digikey are probably available in SA BTW. Maybe RS components and maybe Newark/Farnell. They are all reputable unlike amazon, ebay etc. who are unreliable IC peddlers.